# How to get specific keys from interface using template literal types?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that takes in a string array of `possibleColumns` for a given database table. It then uses the incoming `source` and tries to match it to a column that contain `{source}_id`.

e.g. the `possibleColumns` could contain `["id", "name", "first_id", "second_id"]` and the source is `first` it then checks for any columns called `first_id` and returns it.

The logic is fine but the returned types are not correct, currently it just returns the possible value as any of the columns in that type but I want to use template literal types to just return any values that contain `<value>_id`. As seen in the comments I'm trying to use the `Extract` type but no luck.

```typescript
/**
 * Takes a list of columns for a specific table and a source and checks for any columns that
 * match `${source}_id`.
 * @template T The desired output type
 * @param possibleColumns string array of columns of type T
 * @param source The source to convert in question
 * @returns a key of one of the columns of T or undefined if not matched
 */
export function getProviderIdColumn<T>(possibleColumns: (keyof T)[], source: string) {
    // Attempt to extract only keys that contain _id at the end
    // as Extract<keyof T extends `${infer _}_id` ? keyof T : never, T>
    const providerIdColumn = `${source}_id` as keyof T;
    if (possibleColumns.includes(providerIdColumn)) {
        return providerIdColumn;
    }
```

### Current output

`"id" | "name" | "first_id" | "second_id"`

### Desired output

`"first_id" | "second_id"`

My knowledge of typescript isn't great so please disregard any misused terminology.

### Minimal working example

```typescript
export interface Model {
    id: number,
    name: string | null,
    third_id: string | null,
    source: string,
    first_id: string | null,
    second_id: string | null,
}

/**
 * Takes a list of columns for a specific table and a source and checks for any columns that
 * match `${source}_id`.
 * @template T The desired output type
 * @param possibleColumns string array of columns of type T
 * @param source The source to convert in question
 * @returns a key of one of the columns of T or undefined if not matched
 */
export function getProviderIdColumn<T>(possibleColumns: (keyof T)[], source: string) {
    // Attempt to extract only keys that contain _id at the end
    // as Extract<keyof T extends `${infer _}_id` ? keyof T : never, T>
    const providerIdColumn = `${source}_id` as keyof T;
    if (possibleColumns.includes(providerIdColumn)) {
        return providerIdColumn;
    }
    return undefined;

}

// A function here returns a string array of the keys in Model.
const columnInfo: (keyof Model)[] = ["id", "name", "first_id", "source", "second_id", "third_id"];

const source = "first";

// Returned values here are fine but I want to get the desired output.
const providerIdColumn = getProviderIdColumn<Model>(columnInfo, source);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQgBNgAbOAbwCg5bEiAuOJAVwFsAjNAGhrqUxtgTAM4woyAOZwAPsxalSvOnHQIoYgPoJGcMRKTS5rRcroiILKLlHipZ2iODYISItt36ps+ab60YAAt1dx1bAyNfJSoAXyoqAHoAKiSaJLgAFUwAa2AROEw4UgQxOAh0OBdSdiR89GgCvTBnBDVsOBhMDlI8TDdGiytcAv7sQOdsuoa+gE9KiGq2Wo7AzBg0uDY1sbgAAwASCkHrYBiPXYA6DYABVDYwUjW8DMzxuBIRdWAiMpYYMD+HRmzRuYEwUEEcEgIk+3WAAGEFjV8l5DAUoBC5uV5otltiYMDnqDwZDjsMMm8yXgYBB5kgAG5oeDIOAARxYeRgCFcNygwBgVmWhVyWIqrjw+LeVWRZQqLwaLDcwDUSG+iAqSAg8C2MDG3zSCSooEgsFUiuwXNccEk-IAClAIPSdGgAJJERG4gA8GQAfAAKaGwnoe5FMP0i7EZACUAG0ALrcPSWE7hKRRyj+OAJBJwACCMDuYHgNLgoHEOHgrlIcxF+SCazpnRZHgKxbewDcmezBXyAFEQOWLZ6I3LSwOO0R8gcKMh0Gg4JozjpdnAAPxwEeZOBMVWMqCJ32Zly1eBgB1OkhQN0hpZwAC8e0OVKXRBXmHym4yAG5M604AGIBhBA4RvWoLmQbBqg+ANz2dK93SRJYo3TagVBUPkBSgJAoVgy9r0QpAfxUOJ0P5QU4EVEgVW+H84kSHNczNJALW5bDxj5OAMMFfJClRaRwUxWUVjwWtEGwwgSFIK5j1KaUlhdJB6jDTcJLIWM43vOAYwAIh0bTE20gQhH0uBtLUDQYA8EztKpaynGPUIiGsoIQisuMfyoGT4CpTSzPUMRtI87sACUyKwtV6Uwao8jgdjeg46i4A4QEXTgAB3Ppi1pG02zwD4vh+Sx-j+aTXFKM9HTg-DcU0nL7UqvCEK9VTSH9OSkAU+pEypKMvyAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that by using this [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to extract the `_id` property names:

```typescript
/**
 * Gets a union of the literal types in `T` that end with `_id`.
 */
type IdKeys<T extends any[]> = keyof {
    [Key in T[number] as Key extends `${string}_id` ? Key : never]: null;
};
```

and then use that in the function:

```typescript
/**
 * Takes a list of columns for a specific table and a source and checks for any columns that
 * match `${source}_id`.
 * @template ObjectType The desired output type
 * @param possibleColumns string array of columns of type T
 * @param source The source to convert in question
 * @returns a key of one of the columns of T or undefined if not matched
 */
export function getProviderIdColumn<ObjectType>(
    possibleColumns: (keyof ObjectType)[],
    source: string
): IdKeys<(keyof ObjectType)[]> | undefined {
    // Sadly, we have to have a type assertion, since `source` is type `string`
    const providerIdColumn = `${source}_id` as IdKeys<(keyof ObjectType)[]>;
    if (possibleColumns.includes(providerIdColumn)) {
        return providerIdColumn;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

The result is that in your sample call:

```typescript
const providerIdColumn = getProviderIdColumn<Model>(columnInfo, source);
```

...`providerIdColumn`'s type is `"first_id" | "second_id" | "third_id" | undefined`.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQgBNgAbOAbwCg5bEiAuOJAVwFsAjNAbhrqUxtgTAM4woyAOZwAPsxalSvOnHQIoYgPoJGcMRKTS5rRcroiILKLlHipZ2iODYISItt36ps+ab60YAAt1dx1bAyNfJSoAXyoqAHoAKiSaJLgAcWAYEThMOBYkBFc4CHQ4ILxSBFQoTHIYAE8wYFzkOAADABUOisDMeGA3OAB3GsDOjw6AOjSEqiaWuABJIgBpYEaRAB4uuFBUN1zMJEaAbQBdAD44AF44AGtNssp-ODONxsQkOC6z1k4aAueVyn32IEORFyHQAJBQvIYYlM4AB+OBgphIYAANyBmIU0RivESKTSv0wT2OcGqYlK5RcpHYSFy6GgeT0LWwCDU2AqmA4pDwJyI7IsVlweWG2ECzgeLLZJy+DKZuSCAzJbAG0s6cLF1mASJ0MzJAAFUGwwKQBngAPIcABWzhgXWaeC6MrgJBE6mAIssMDALHgi2AprAmDqbDgkBE3oFwAAwhBGWxmXo7IY8lA6l8XsrU7kXiHfmGI4I9JZ9b8PXqJTAIHAXEhcbBvnAAI4sVowYpIU1QbJWNP5J658quPBFj35tMvPZswokNRYkXc5gQeCamDS31zKigSCt9CFbA9kqSbIABSgEGxOjQqyTKaQ2ztjtPLpaVwAFG8Y3HBSfFUmG-UcXjfJ1P2AABKS4ABo3lrYR0wiKhoKYVZPh2UDnnKCCP1dWDrh8RdgGXX1XhUBIEjgABlTAiFIRo4NGPB+lxCoG3YoUKldEEnFgXsWO9JAJQ6JDegQVU+PEjNJA6N4m1pMAbzvEgoEfZMmTuHV4UrXBDSIXpMFyTDNmwsC8IdSDCMuK4HEQcpv3-BB4yAgtpmQbBGS9ZzVPvDSiHcpBoOgyiVDoAcYCHaN-PUzTnwcuIVCimLSPIoheDiRIaIAQVUE8zx+GUBzgVKoGHFDvAjHM6T6PBRzaH5CBIUhZiU+AZ2WJBWR0s43gAIh0AaEJUAaBCEEbBrUDQYA8KaxqQha6AGpwm1CIhltoAaghCeaEOBEy4BwxoXhasgiOJDqK3FPB7gGmaxAG4lqLgAAlQcKoo7F6i7XISqFUryLgDggxWUYTmDBsL2DD0vR9P0g0DGB2tcZS4ofIKtNTHSYevW8AoSpltnO0gfy6nqIGE-SYN4V66AAPRRKggA)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this and for giving me advice on making a minimal reproducible example, been stuck on it for days!

Comment: It was an interesting one! Glad that helped. :-)

Comment: @JoelAdams - What do you want the call to look like? Something like `const providerIdColumn = getProviderIdColumn<Model>(columnInfo, source, disallow);`?

Comment: Incoming request would look something like 
```const providerIdColumn = getProviderIdColumn<T, K extends T = any>(columnInfo, source>
const providerIdColumn = `${source}_id` as K != undefined ? Omit<IdKeys<(keyof T)[]>, K> : IdKeys<(keyof T)[]);
```

call it like `const providerIdColumn = getProviderIdColumn<Model, "company_id">(columnInfo, source)`

Comment: @JoelAdams - That call doesn't supply the necessary runtime value to the function. The function can't weed out the value if it doesn't have it at runtime. Am I misunderstanding something? If doing it just at the type level, you could use `Omit<Model, "duedil_id">` but you have to do that for both the call and the `columnInfo` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/WJXVZN)). Alternatively, you could narrow the type once you have it with a type guard, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOPoW).